# How use regular expressions to compare an input with a set?

Tags: python, regex

I would like a regular expression python code to:

- 1) Take an input of characters
- 2) Outputs the characters in all lower case letters
- 3) Compares this output in a python set.

I am no good at all with regular expressions.

Comment: Why do you want a regular expression?  Is the set a set of words or the set of all characters appearing in a string or something else?  What are you comparing this input to?

Comment: Outline your problem and we may give a better solution than the one you have proposed

Comment: It is a keyword system, but I don't think I need to have a regular expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why bother?

```
>>> 'FOO'.lower() in set(('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
True
>>> 'Quux'.lower() in set(('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
False
```

Comment: @Alex: Having a question word doesn't necessarily make it a question.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that will suffice for now. I am still going to work on a regex version however.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry, it sounded like a question when I read it.

Comment: @DrWolfe Thank Ignacio, he answered your question, not me :)

Answer (score 0):

After much google searching, and with trial an error, I a created a solution that works to separate multiple words from the input of characters.

```
import re

keywords = ('cars', 'jewelry', 'gas')
pattern = re.compile('[a-z]+', re.IGNORECASE)
txt = 'GAS, CaRs, Jewelrys'

keywords_found = pattern.findall(txt.lower())

n = 0

for i in keywords_found:
    if i in keywords:
        print keywords_found[n]
    n = n + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your self-answer would be better using a `set` rather than that loop.

Using `i` for a text variable and `n` for an index is very counter-intuitive. And `keywords_found` is a misnomer.

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> keywords = set(('cars', 'jewelry', 'gas'))
>>> pattern = re.compile('[a-z]+', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> txt = 'GAS, CaRs, Jewelrys'
>>> text_words = set(pattern.findall(txt.lower()))
>>> print "keywords:", keywords
keywords: set(['cars', 'gas', 'jewelry'])
>>> print "text_words:", text_words
text_words: set(['cars', 'gas', 'jewelrys'])
>>> print "text words in keywords:", text_words & keywords
text words in keywords: set(['cars', 'gas'])
>>> print "text words NOT in keywords:", text_words - (text_words & keywords)
text words NOT in keywords: set(['jewelrys'])
>>> print "keywords NOT in text words:", keywords - (text_words & keywords)
keywords NOT in text words: set(['jewelry'])
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this later today.

Comment: @DrWolfe: Note that `keywords` should be a set also, not a tuple, for efficiency's sake -- reread Ignacio's answer.